# Is it possible injecting memcached in Apache iBatis?

Tags: memcached, ibatis

I've been working on a complex project using a and distribuited application that requires caching SQL queries: since I've been using iBatis framework, I'd like to use memcached - sysadmin requires it - as caching engine.
Is it possible? If yes, does anyone know existing solutions/implementations?
I already know OSCACHE works also in cluster, but I'd like to know if using the existing architecture is possible, before switching to a new one.
Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

iBatis returns one or more JavaBeans, which in turn may contain nested Lists of JavaBeans.  A JavaBean is just a Java object that adheres to certain simple [conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans), one of which is that it implement the Serializable interface.  If it does, you can [serialize](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) a JavaBean structure into a String, and deserialize that String back into a deep copy of the original JavaBean structure.

So let's assume you ensure all your result objects are declared to "implement Serializable".  JavaBeans have such a simple structure that the default Java object serialization/deserialization mechanisms don't need to be overridden, which is good.

These serialized Strings are the *values* you put into your memcached cluster's distributed hash map.  In each of your Java methods that runs a query and returns its results, you first lookup the existing result in memcached, and if it *is* there and hasn't expired, you deserialize it into the JavaBeans that (presumably) your query would have returned.  If the query result is *not* found in memcached, then you query the database through iBatis, but before you return the result, you serialize it into a String and store that value in memcached.

The next question is what to use for the memcached query result *keys*.  Something like

```
YourIbatisQueryName + ":" + FirstParameterValue + ":" + SecondParameterValue
```

should work (eg, "SelectStackOverflowReputation:Simone:Tripodi").

You're almost finished.  The final step is to figure out how long a query result can be cached without becoming invalid.  Perhaps you can establish a different expiration time for each query, or maybe you need a manual cache invalidation mechanism.  Caching query results even for just a few minutes can have very strong effects on your application's scalability.

Note: A variation on this approach is to not use the default Java serialization, but use XML, or JSON, or some other format.  If you choose XML or JSON, look into a serialization framework like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to serialize/deserialize your JavaBeans into XML Strings and back again.

Answer (score 0):

extends cacheController ,but alias use add global

Comment: Can you edit your answer to be more specific on the actions needed.